# Clock frequency divider circuit (divide by 2) using D flip flop

Tags: digital-logic, frequency, flipflop, frequency-divider

[image]I was trying to implement frequency divider by 2 using D flip flop with the logic connection of ~Q to D input. I provide 2x clock frequency of 50% Duty cycle in the hardware where D flip flop is made up using the basic nand gates.

I am getting a weird signal at Q output which kind of looks like a sine wave in the oscilloscope. I don't know what I missed out. Could someone help me with this?

[image]

**Clock frequency used**: 5 MHz

Comment: show how your circuit looks like, show the output you got.

Comment: Note that a square wave becomes a sine at high frequencies if your output can not cope with such high frequencies. Or if your scope can not cope with those high frequencies. (And then if you increase the frequency the sine wave amplitude becomes smaller and smaller and disappears)

Comment: is my circuit correct? or should i use some pull up or pull down ~Q?

Comment: What about the frequency you used.,,.how you tested waveforms etc ..?

Comment: 5mhz and tested waveforms using osciloscope at the ends of ~Q and Q

Comment: Which IC did you use?

Comment: *5mhz and tested waveforms...* I guess you mean 5 MHz? for 5 mHz every cycle takes 200 seconds, that's not practical. But 5 MHz can be a challenge to get right. Start with 1 kHz and see what you get.

Comment: You say you made your DFF from basic NAND gates. Show us the actual circuit -- it sounds like you didn't create a true edge-triggered function.

Comment: yes i have added the ciruit made by nand gates and it 5MHz and the ic i used is sn74lvc2g132dcur

Comment: if i use a direct d flip flop ic then it should work ...isn't it?

Comment: That's a D latch. Not D flip flop.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, you have not created a true edge-triggered FF, but rather just a latch. When your CLK input is high, the negative feedback from Q' to D causes the outputs to oscillate as fast as they can, and that's the "weird" waveform you're seeing.

Comment: oh, now i get it!! and what would be output (Q) when there is no clock given( initial condition when the Flip flop is just on)?

Comment: It isn't predictable. There are two stable states, and they're equally likely.